# TouchScript with Unity WebGL

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, websocket, udp, unity-webgl

I'm developing a website which I want it to run a Unity WebGL app. This app for a touch screen which can detect objects with codes similar to QR code, due to TUIO protocol. When I put an object here, app is detecting the object and do whatever I want to do in the code, such showing an image, playing an animation etc. App is working well on Windows but I want it to work on WebGL.

My problem is, I can only use TouchScript SDK, as I see the only SDK in Unity for TUIO and actually quite enough for my needs, but doesn't support WebGL officially. I tried to change some parts of the code to make it compatible. However, at the end it gave me the SocketException below;

```
SocketException: Success
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor (System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily addressFamily, System.Net.Sockets.SocketType socketType, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType protocolType) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

To solve this problem, I've made a research and I have found that someone else had the same problem with a different SDK.

[Socket Exception in Unity WebGL](https://forum.unity.com/threads/getting-socket-exception-in-unity-webgl.746276/)

I don't have much experience with web stuff and as I understood, since Unity WebGL is using WebSockets only but TouchScript is using UDP, I'm getting this error.

My question is, refactoring the SDK, i.e. using WebSocket rather than UDP for connection, is a good idea or can you suggest anything else such as another SDK or whatever you can suggest?

I'm thinking to change this part of the code with WebSocketClient, but I'm not sure if it will work.

```
public TuioServer(int port)
        {
            Port = port;
            udpReceiver = new UDPReceiver(Port, consumeParsingExceptions: false);
            udpReceiver.MessageReceived += handlerOscMessageReceived;
            udpReceiver.ErrorOccured += handlerOscErrorOccured;
        }
```

Comment: yeah in general WebGL doesn't have access to local sockets